# wpa_cli level command always fails

Tags: debugging, wpa, wpa-cli

I'm trying to set the debug level of `wpa_cli` using the level command.
It doesn't matter if I use interactive mode or direct commands the level command always fails.

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 level 1

=> FAIL
```

And interactive mode:

```
wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.3
Copyright (c) 2004-2014, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'wlan0'

Interactive mode

> level 5
FAIL
```

What is the correct way to get this to work?

I'm trying to get debug messages for when a connection fails (because of a wrong psk or something)

Comment: Sorry that's not exactly what I am looking for, I have no problems connecting to my network but I would like to be able to debug the problem for the rare occasion that the connection fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Interactive mode type `log_level`:

```
> log_level 
Current level: INFO
Timestamp: 0
```

Then type `log_level debug` :

```
> log_level debug
OK
```

Verify using the command `log_level` :

```
> log_level 
Current level: DEBUG
Timestamp: 0
```

Comment: Hi @GAD3R, Please let me know how to get the Timestamp value. No need to print 0 value. Please guide me.